# Applications where rank-1 matrices are useful

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, applications, rank-1-matrices

I am trying to list down applications where having a rank-1 matrix is advantageous. I know only of 2D convolution which boils down to a series of 1D convolutions if filter response is separable.

Can members add any other application here?

Comment: Look into principal component analysis

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33289/339790)

Answer (score 0):

The Spectral Theorem is about decomposing a matrix as a linear combination of rank-one orthogonal projections.

Diagonalization is about decomposing a matrix as a linear combination of rank-one idempotents.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer. I am familiar with "diagonalization" but have not looked into it from the perspective of idempotents....

Comment: Diagonalization is $A=PDP^{-1}$, with $D=\sum d_kE_{kk}$. Then $$A=\sum d_k (PE_{kk}P^{-1}),$$ where each $PE_{kk}P$ is a rank-one idempotent.